# how to use pandas and python and ta-lib to build dataframe from many csv's in order calculate technical indicators

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

I can use the code below to build a frame from a single file (which has ticker, date, OHLC and volume) and to then use TA-lib to build the technical indicators. Works fine. I can also use "glob" to combine thousands of csv's into a blob and import into SQL and then run python script against sql (with other plugins) to parse the values and build technical indicator values, however, what is happening is that the moving averages are not being calculated for each symbol individually, but instead, just calculated across all of the symbols in the SQL table (or csv) , thereby messing everything up. In other words, on say row 11, the ticker has changed from A to B and the first 10 rows were all ticker A, TA-lib is just using the data on row 11 as if its part of the data for ticker A but now, it's ticker B. It should start over with each unique ticker. If I can find a way to build individual dataframes for each csv file, run the calculations, and then output into thousands of newly created csv files (one for each unique ticker) that will solve the problem. I can also avoid SQL all together. Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import talib

csv_file = "C:\\Users\\Bob\\IBM.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

Symbol = df['Symbol']
Date = df['Date']
Open = df['Open']
High = df['High']
Low = df['Low']
Close = df['Close']
Volume = df['Volume']

from talib import SMA,T3

SMA = SMA(Close, timeperiod=5)
print(SMA)

T3 = T3(Close, timeperiod=5, vfactor=0)
print(T3)

total_df = pd.concat([Symbol, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, SMA, T3])
print(total_df)
total_df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

************** here is my latest code below*************

```
import pandas as pd
import talib
import glob, os
from talib import SMA, T3
import os

csv_file_list = glob.glob(r"H:\EOD_DATA_RECENT\TEST\\*.csv")

print(csv_file_list)

for csv_file in csv_file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    print(df)

df['SMA'] = SMA(df['AdjustedClose'], timeperiod=5)
# print(df['SMA'])

df['T3'] = T3(df['AdjustedClose'], timeperiod=5, vfactor=0)
# print(df['T3'])

print(df)
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is kind of unclear right now because your code doesn't really show what you are trying to do that doesn't work, and it refers to thing like SMA() and T3() that aren't reproducible if someone else tried to run this. Try creating a [MCWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways, I believe, you can do this. If you want separate files you just read in your csv files in a loop, perform the action and write file to disk. Also, I'm making some assumptions here...

```
from talib import SMA,T3 # move this up to the top with other modules

csv_file_list = [however you get list of files]

for csv_file in csv_file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    
    #I'm not sure why are reading these into series, I think you can call them directly
    #Symbol = df['Symbol']
    #Date = df['Date']
    #Open = df['Open']
    #High = df['High']
    #Low = df['Low']
    #Close = df['Close']
    #Volume = df['Volume']
    
    df['SMA'] = SMA(df['Close'], timeperiod=5) # create column in df automatically
    print(df['SMA'])
    
    df['T3'] = T3(df['Close'], timeperiod=5, vfactor=0) # create column in df automatically
    print(df['T3'])
    
    # df is already built from above, so don't need next line
    #total_df = pd.concat([Symbol, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, SMA, T3])
    print(df)
    Symbol = df.Symbol[0]
    fn = Symbol + '_indicators.csv
    df.to_csv(fn)
```

The second way would be to read all csv files into dfs and `concat`. You can save this one df to a csv 'master' if you will, then use `groupby` to get the SMA and T3 by ticker. If you have thousands of tickers, this might be too cumbersome but does alleviate having to read thousands of files. I do both methods depending on what type of analysis I'm running. A df of 500 tickers is manageable from a compute time perspective as long as what you are doing is coded correctly. Otherwise, I look a one ticker at a time, then go to the larger df.

Try the first reworked suggested code and see what you come up with.

Comment: Thanks alot for this. I am using the following to get a list of files:

Comment: I am using glob.glob to get a list of files:  Then, when I print that first dataframe, I see the two files listed in the directory" ['H:\\\\EOD_DATA_RECENT\\\\TEST\\BCV.csv', 'H:\\\\EOD_DATA_RECENT\\\\TEST\\ERH.csv']. 
                                      
That's good but when I print the dataframe , or print the dataframe for SMA or T3, I get results from only the second file in the folder (ERH.csv)

Comment: Can you update the post with all your updated code?

Comment: import pandas as pd
    import talib
    import glob, os
    from talib import SMA,T3
    import os

    csv_file_list = glob.glob(r"H:\\EOD_DATA_RECENT\\TEST\\*.csv")
    print(csv_file_list)

    for csv_file in csv_file_list:
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        print(df)
    
    df['SMA'] = SMA(df['AdjustedClose'], timeperiod=5)  
    df['T3'] = T3(df['AdjustedClose'], timeperiod=5, vfactor=0)

Comment: i have no idea how to format code in this comments box. It was fine when I pasted it. I cant even use a carriage return in the this box or it submits the comment.

Comment: I see one of my problems. I had the following which was breaking something: csv_file_list = glob.glob(r"H:\\EOD_DATA_RECENT\\TEST\\*.csv"). There should not have been double back slashes after H:\\ and after RECENT\\. Should be like csv_file_list = glob.glob(r"H:\EOD_DATA_RECENT\TEST\\*.csv"). Ill play around some more now that I have fixed this. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: No worries. It’s usually the little things. If you need upload code edit your post, not in the comments. If you still need help please share code where your stuck

Comment: Thank you guys very much. never used stack overflow before. Could you possibly give me an example of how to capture the symbol, as you mentioned in the last line of your example code? I think I am getting the proper output in the terminal but when I do the df.to_csv("test.csv"), I am only getting output from one of my csv files. I guess I need this fn to create separate ones based on filename. I will put latest code when I edit my post. Not sure if I will be overwriting earlier wording and code. I will try not to.

Comment: I updated the last three lines to show how to capture the ticker symbol. Assuming you still have Symbol as a column. This looks at the Symbol column and [0] is the first row. The other way is to split the csv file name and get that it way. If you're happy with the answer, please accept it.

Comment: yes and I got it working and now can proceed. Very appreciative of your time and expertise. So, yes, the answer is accepted (I dont see any way to accept it myself).